# HTML5 Time Tag Undefined / Not Set / Null

Tags: html, datetime, time, tags, undefined

Is there a way to set HTML5 Time Tag to **undefined**?

Imagine listing several events loaded from database, some of them have valid datetime set; others are NULL simply because the time of the event have not been decided yet.

```
<time datetime="n/a">[ date not yet set ]</time>
```

I don't want to omit the tag completely as it is part of the layout. I could of course use span/div instead, but... any suggestions?

EDIT: I'm looking for a **[W3C valid](http://validator.w3.org/nu/)** solution!

Comment: If the time of the event hasn't been decided yet then it's not a time, so you shouldn't use a `<time>` element to represent that at all.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I'll use <span> instead.